# C error with using else macro "expected parameter declarator"

Tags: c, if-statement, error-handling, macros, c99

I wrote the following C code (according to the C99 standard) and it ran with no problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
printf("Running on Windows");
#endif

void test(int x);

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

but adding `else` caused so much errors (around 12) what's the problem with the new code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
printf("Running on Windows");
#else
printf("Running on Windows");
#endif
```

Some of the errors:

```
error: expected parameter declarator
expected ')'
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
error: conflicting types for 'printf'
```

Comment: You can't have a function call in filescope. The `printf("...");` needs to be inside of a function.

Comment: You need to post the context where you are using the macro. As stated by @PSkocik, this macro would need to be in a function so the call to printf compiles correctly.

Comment: I don't understand why the first code worked then?

Comment: Post the context!

Comment: I did it, refresh the page

Comment: @clark_smith Likely because `_WIN32` was *not* defined and so the preprocessor didn't insert the `printf` call.

Comment: If you're using a compiler like `gcc`/`clang`/`tcc`, run it with `-E` to see the preprocessed output textually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use conditional compilation the preprocessor adds code to your program before the compile step.
So, if the symbol _WIN32 exists, then you are effectively saying

```
printf("Running on Windows");

void test(int x);

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

and that is syntactically incorrect because you have executable code (a call to printf) outside all functions.

If you didn't have a problem before you added the '#else' then that was because the symbol _WIN32 doesn't exist and the preprocessor wasn't adding the printf statement to your code.

Comment: So if _Win32 exists #ifdef _WIN32 and #endif will be erased right (and only the printf () call remains)? But is this checked every time I run the program or only at the preprocessor stage?

Comment: Yes, and at the preprocessor step